# How to loop many objects inside array to collect a specific item?

Tags: javascript

I have this object:

```js
data: [
  {
    name: bed,
    price: [
      {
        id: 2,
        color: red
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        color: blue
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: lego,
    price: [
      {
        id: 5,
        color: red
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        color: blue
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: mouse,
    price: [
      {
        id: 7,
        color: red
      },
      {
        id: 9,
        color: blue
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to collect the `id` prices of each object like this:

```js
ids: [ [ 2, 4 ], [ 5, 6 ], [ 7, 9 ] ]
```

I tried this but it doesn’t work:

```js
ids() {
  const datas = this.data;
  let idPrices = null;
  let prices = [];
  
  for (let priceId in datas) {
    prices.push(priceId.price);
  }
  
  idPrices = prices.map((prices) => prices.map((price) => price.id));
  
  return idPrices;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const data=[{name:"bed",price:[{id:2,color:"red"},{id:4,color:"blue"}]},{name:"lego",price:[{id:5,color:"red"},{id:6,color:"blue"}]},{name:"mouse",price:[{id:7,color:"red"},{id:9,color:"blue"}]}];

const ids = data.map(e => e.price.map(f => f.id));
console.log(ids);
```

Comment: thank you spectric is logic your code but is don't always work

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one helps you? I think it's possible to do it more simple but this is the best i can do at 1:30AM. :)

```js
const data = [
      {name: 'bed', price:[{id: 2 ,color: 'red'}, {id: 4, color: 'blue'}]},
      {name: 'lego', price:[{id: 5 ,color: 'red'}, {id: 6, color:'blue'}]},
      {name: 'mouse', price:[{id: 7 ,color: 'red'}, {id: 9, color: 'blue'}]}
      ]
      
      
let idPrices = [];
for (const i in data) {
    let prices = [];

 for (const j in data[i].price) {
  prices.push(data[i].price[j].id)

}
  idPrices.push(prices)

}
console.log(idPrices);
```

Comment: the problem is that it does not loop inside this object i don't understand why `Array []` always empty

Comment: You should be using a `for` or `for...of` loop on arrays not `for...in` see: [Array iteration and for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#array_iteration_and_for...in)

Comment: my array data is that `Array []
​
0: Object { id: Getter & Setter, reference: Getter & Setter, url: Getter & Setter, … }
​
1: Object { id: Getter & Setter, reference: Getter & Setter, url: Getter & Setter, … }
​
2: Object { id: Getter & Setter, reference: Getter & Setter, url: Getter & Setter, … }
​
__ob__: Object { value: (3) […], dep: {…}, vmCount: 0 }
​
length: 3
`

Comment: You mean inside your for in? Please check my loop and yours and you will see the difference. In "for (let priceId in datas) { prices.push(priceId.price);}" the priceId doesn't containt the object it containts the key. You should try to understand this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in .it also would help if you would play around with console.log() inside your loop. Try: console.log(priceId) /*result:1,2,3*/ and you will understand why priceId.price is undefined

Comment: @justcasper your code is good but the problem is my data after several tests is don't loop inside the first loop  i don't understand why.

Comment: Can you give me an example of your data? You can replace the critical stuff with dummies. Btw. Spectric has the better solution.

Comment: exactly @spectric is the best solution finally i have find my problem the loop is good but my datas don't loop if  the function called in the `async created` (vue js) but is the `async fetch` the loop work fine i don't understand why but is work thank you all for your reponses